# Critical boot error

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, grub, antergos

While I was cleaning up my pc, I accidentally uninstalled a package I shouldn't have uninstalled (can't really remember what I uninstalled thought ).

As a consequence, a total of 599 packages were deleted (including linux-lts) and of course , now I can't boot.

If I try to boot antergos from grub I get the following output:

```
Booting 'Antergos Linux'... 
error: file '/vmlinuz-linux' not found
loading initial ram-disk...
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

I haven't done any backup recently and I have been working really hard lately with my pc.
I really can't reinstall any Linux distro now, so, what should I do now?

Comment: Boot from a live media and reinstall linux from the chroot.

Comment: Also, if you have important files you want to back up, you could do that from a live media.  Before you start trying to re-install kernels and update bootloaders etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[THIS ANSWER HAS NOT BEEN TESTED.  Some recovery operations cause data loss e.g. if applied incorrectly.  You mentioned you do not have an up-to-date backup.  You could boot your preferred live media, find your files, and make an up-to-date backup copy of them before you try anything further.  Think carefully about where you can save them to.]

Adapt the steps from https://antergos.com/wiki/miscellaneous/how-to-fix-grub-with-efi-boot/ .

Roughly:

1. Boot the "LiveIso".
2. (Added step): Establish a network connection.  It might help to read the relevant section of the Arch Install Guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide#Connect_to_the_Internet
3. Mount your partitions under `/mnt`.
4. Use `arch-chroot /mnt`.
5. (Instead of regenerating GRUB): download and install a kernel package using your distribution's package manager.

If you find you have removed other packages which are critical to the boot, you will have to repeat these steps.  Looking at the [Arch Install Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide), I would suggest trying to run `pacman -S base` while you are still inside the chroot.  I even suspect this command might install a kernel package (if it is not already installed).

To be on the safe side, you may as well use the command to regenerate GRUB config as well, `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Remember, after you `exit` the chroot, to `umount` all the partitions you mounted, and shut down cleanly.

Comment: Thank you for your precious feedback. I'll write here below what I did.